# Free transform Matrix in .net

Tags: graphics, matrix, transformation

My requirement is to transform a rectangular image 2D to a Quadrilateral (perspective view 3D)and the opposite. By opposite I mean that you have picture of a carpet on the floor, assuming that we recognized its corners, I like to have its flat rectangular pattern.

The project is in C# so the Transform matrix only supports Afine transform not Prespective (free form).

Do you know any library for doing this?

Here there is an impleim, entation from 2D to 3D but not the other way. By the way, it is uses a trick rather than a transform matrix and ends to some incorrect results sometimes:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36145/Free-Image-Transformation

Comment: based on [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441597/how-to-calculate-what-matrix-will-transform-specified-points-to-other-specified) you will be able to create the on your own

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Convert command of ImageMagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php)

It has some library that you can add to your code and also a command line executable. 
I have created a process and passed image addresses to it. Check [this Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028228/calling-image-magick-commands-from-net)