# Using libpng in C#

Tags: c#, .net, image, libpng

if you want to save the image in `PNG` format you can use `ImageFormat` class of .Net.
But this class doesn't implemented compression for `PNG` files.
And for some reasons i can't save my file in JPEG format.
After Some researched i know `libpng` is the official PNG reference library.
But i can't find anything for using it in .net framework.
Does anyone know about this library and using it in .NET?

[About libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html)

Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: did you tried - https://code.google.com/p/sharpapng/ ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418454/c-seeking-png-compression-algorithm-library

Comment: @Vinoth i saw this page but not said how to use libpng

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative: [PngCs](https://code.google.com/p/pngcs/)

> But this class doesn't implemented compression for PNG files

What on earth does that mean? PNG is compressed by design.

Comment: Does that apply to prefiltering too? I think that depends on the software.

Answer (score 2):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is a very nice library that allows you (among other things) create PNG files.
[Magick.NET](http://magick.codeplex.com/) is the .Net wrapper for this library. Using this library, you can simply convert/create image formats. E.g. from their [documentation](http://magick.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Convert%20image&referringTitle=Documentation):

```
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage("Snakeware.gif"))
{
   image.Write("Snakeware.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,what about compression?

Comment: Documentation on how to use the compression can be found here: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#png_quality. Note that you don't necessarily need to use the library: you can also simply do the conversion in the command line using processes. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028228/calling-image-magick-commands-from-net

Answer (score 1):

Since libpng it's written in C ( ANSI C, even better ) you can build a bridge between that library and your C# application -> [Use a C library from C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093292/use-a-c-library-from-c-sharp-code)

There are also other options, such as [freeimage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) and the port of `ImageMagick` to .net but in this case it's still unclear to me what kind of project is this one, I don't get if it's official or not, if it's already dead or alive, if you are interested you can search for that name.

In simple terms PNG it's a open standard where JPEG it's a world full of patents and royalties, for this reason some libraries do not offer jpeg features or they offer a limited set of jpeg related features/algorithms. PNG it's also a real imaging standard about a file format definition, jpeg it's more like a container.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I look up for the method that i can compress png file.what's your suggestion?

Comment: JPEG isn't a "world full of patents and royalties".  You might be confusing JPEG with JPEG2000.